# My teammates keep getting between me and the bad guys. Can I shoot through them?

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-3-multiplayer

In Mass Effect 3's multiplayer, my helpful allies keep getting in between me and the people that I'm trying to put bullets into.

As you might guess, this is non-optimal for everyone concerned.

I haven't seen a damage meter other than my own, so I can't tell whether my bullets are hurting my teammates.

**Can I safely shoot through my teammates, and, if I hit an enemy on the other side, will the shots do damage?**

Comment: Well I know it doesn't hurt them, I'd have to test to see if it actually hits the other side.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The answer to your question is... yes and no.**

As far as shooting through your teammates, you can do this -- somewhat. Depending on where you hit your allies, the shots will, in fact, go through. If you hit your allies in their arms or parts of their legs, the shots will go through and hit whatever is on the other side. Attempting to fire shots through their upper or lower torso will stop the bullets however.

To test this, aim at the ground through an ally's arm or the edge of their leg. You'll notice when you squeeze off a round, the shot will visibly ricochet off the ground. Depending on the surface, you'll see sparks or dirt appear. If you attempt to do this through their upper or lower torso, the "ricochet" effect will not appear, e.g. the round did not make it through the ally's model.

Assuming you can get an ally's arm or leg to line up between your gun and an enemy, your shot will, in fact, damage the enemy. It's just more effective to actually see what you're hitting, obviously.

Comment: Huh, I didn't realize you could do this. I'd thought there was friendly fire like in ME2 so I'd been carefully avoiding shooting through them.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can shoot through them just fine. You can even fire missiles through them! Better yet, they block incoming fire... so for example if your shields just went out, and there's no good cover, having a friend stand in front of you can save your life! Of course it might cost theirs.